# @RequestParam with pojo inside pojo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public MyObject myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "prop1", required = false) String prop1,
    @RequestParam(value = "prop2", required = false) String prop2,
    @RequestParam(value = "prop3", required = false) String prop3) { ... }
```

And I have this instead many parameter and it's working:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;

    //Getters and setters
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public MyObject myAction(MyObject myObject)
```

But I have problem when I am trying avoid duplicate

```
 public class MyClass {
        private MyObject param;

        //Getters and setters
        ...
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public MyObject myAction(MyClass myClass)
```

What should my `url` with parameters look like now?

```
param={prop1=a1&prop2=a2&prop3=a3&} ?
```

Comment: prefix them with `param.` the name of the request parameters follow the path.

Comment: it's a good practice?

Comment: why wouldn't it. How else would you bind a form to a complex structure.

Comment: Because I thought it is better to have a separate object

Comment: You already have an object? What if you have a car with an engine. Why would you need 2 backing objects use do `engine.capacity`? Next to that you will run into issues if objects have properties with the same name. A car could have a name or color, while another element could have that as well (like a tire). how would you differentiate between `color` and `color`? If you don't use the whole path?

Comment: I just want avoid duplicate one object. So I want create separate general object

Comment: why not send the param data via request body and ditch the request parameters? It's much easier when you have this complex data structures

Answer (score -1):

Actually requesting in same way works

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/action")
    public Person myAction(Person person) {
        return person;
    }

}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

URL Request:
`http://localhost:8080/action?name=George&address=UK`

Response

```
{
   "name":"George",
   "address":"UK"
}
```